# Intercept when a view it's visible on screen

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView contains a certain number of views, and i would that my code execute an AsyncTask when the last view inside scroll becomes visible. 
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this.getActivity());
    sv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this is executed when it becomes visible for the first time
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
If you want this from an element inside the scrollView, If you are using an adapter then

```
// Adapter class ie ArrayAdapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView;
    //....
    myView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this is executed when it becomes visible for the first time
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: I would like to intercept when a view inside ScrollView is visible on screen, not the entire ScrollView

Comment: Ok, tall views have this method, I supose you are using an adapter, then when you create the view which go inside de list view

    View v = ...;
    v.post(new Runnable() {
    ...
    });

Comment: i'm using a ScrollView view with a LinearLayout inside, wich contains views

Comment: for every view you want to intercept use the post method then. Or implement this in the last view that will be visible. If you don't know which will be the last, then for every post method that has been called, increase +1 a counter, when the counter is equal to the all views that exists in the scrollview, then you can call de asynctask.

But I think that if you call the method call in the scroll view, the runnable will be called when all the inner views has been visible.